# Simple Port Forwarding

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall, iptables, router

I have searched and searched and tried several different things and have not been able to fina solution.

Here's my situation:

**node1** has 2 interfaces: **eth0** (Public IP: 56.X.X.X), and **eth1** (Private IP: 10.X.X.X)

**node2** has 2 interfaces: **eth0** (Public IP: 56.X.X.X), and **eth1** (Private IP: 10.X.X.X)

Each node is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

From this setup **node1** and **node2** each have access to the internet but also connect to each other privately through a LAN.

What I want to accomplish is have **node1** be a **firewall** and **proxy server** for **node2** and many other nodes which I will deploy later. **node1** will have the only access to the internet as I will disable **eth0** on **node2** so that **node2** only has access to anything on its private network.

Simply put, how can I forward a **www** request that comes into **node1** and on **eth0** and forward it to **node2** using **eth1** while **node2** will act as the webserver for that request?

After following the example below, here is my iptables -L:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.182.43.193       state NEW tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             10.182.43.193       state NEW tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is my iptables -t nat -L

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       all  --  anywhere             firewall            to:10.182.43.193 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assign some arbitrary IP addresses to make this clear.  Substitute in your real addresses.

node1 eth0: 56.0.0.1
node1 eth1: 10.0.0.1
node2 eth0: 56.0.0.2
node2 eth1: 10.0.0.2

If node1 is to be your gateway/firewall machine, you'll need to run [iptables](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-dnat.html) to handle the NAT/forwarding.

```
# iptables config on node1
# set up a destination nat from 56.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 56.0.0.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2
# open port 80/443
iptables -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.2 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -d 10.0.0.2 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
# related/established traffic
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

You do not need eth0 on node2 to be configured.  Rather, you need to configure the 56.0.0.2 IP address on node1 to use it uniquely to map to node2.

Comment: When I run `iptables -A PREROUTING -d 56.0.0.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2` I get an error: "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name." Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I'm copying from my live config which has the table name on a different line for the entire section.  You'll need to add -t nat to that line.  I'll update above.

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested, and applied the iptables and confirmed the application, and now i try to http://{firewall-ip} and it just hangs. Any ideas on this? This seemed to always be the issue no matter what I tried.

Comment: You need to connect to node2 public IP: 56.0.0.2.  First, check that you can connect to node2 private IP from node1.  From node1, telnet node2 80.  Also, make sure you configure node2 public IP on node1 as I stated above.

Comment: I'm really new to this, how do I configure node2 public IPon node1? Are you talking about the hosts file?

Comment: ifconfig eth0:1 56.0.0.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 (or equivalent netmask).  I'm not really an Ubuntu man but you should look that up in their documentation on how they do it the Ubuntu way.

Comment: So this is supposed to take all web traffic that comes into node1 to route to node2 correct?

Comment: No, not exactly correct.  Only the web traffic that comes into node1, destined to node2's public IP address, configured as a NAT, will be send to node2.  Connecting to node1's public IP address will still direct web traffic to node1's web server, if one exists at all.

Comment: How can I take any traffic directed to node1's port 80 to forward to node2's web server thats hosted through the private IP. That is possible isnt it? Using node1 as a proxy server?

Comment: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 56.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If node2 is supposed to have its own IP address, then you don't need port forwarding, you need proxy ARP and routing.

On node2 disable eth0 and add the public IP to any other interface, eg:

```
ip addr add 56.0.0.2/32 dev eth1
```

On node1 set up the route to the node2 via eth1:

```
ip route add 56.0.0.2 dev eth1
```

and enable proxy ARP responses on eth0 (so node1 will answer for ARP requests for node2):

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp
```

This will make all traffic to node2 go through node1. You may then set up iptables rules to limit it like any other forwarded traffic. This doesn't do any application-level proxying, but you can still achieve that with iptables rules.

Setting these permanently generally depends on distribution, I don't know Ubuntu well enough, but the 'proxy_arp' setting can probably be set in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp = 1
```

Ip address on node2's eth1 should be added to the interface configuration (but without any netmask! or with prefix length '/32'), there should also be a place to put the static routes (/etc/sysconfig/static-routes on my system).